# Applying the identity $\sin^2 + \cos^2=1$ without any other trigonometric simplifications

Tags: simplifying-expressions, trigonometry

Mathematica does not automatically simplify $\sin^2 + \cos^2 =1$, but applying any kind of trigonometric simplification results in not only that identity being applied but also all kind of trig identities, usually resulting in the trig functions being of multiple summed variables. I want to just apply the Pythagorean identity without any other ones. Is there a way to do this? So far I have tried using replacement rules but that is very cumbersome.

Comment: Did you include arguments? Either `Sin[x]^2 + Cos[x]^2 /. Cos[z_]^2 -> 1 - Sin[z]^2` or `Sin[x]^2 + Cos[x]^2 // Simplify` evaluate to `1`

Comment: Problems with code often require code for the problem to be solved. Consider including an example if you want more than just the simplest comments.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Welcome to MMA SE! I believe you might be looking for

```
Simplify[expr, Trig -> False, 
 TransformationFunctions -> {Automatic, (# /. Sin[a_]^2 + Cos[a_]^2 :> 1) &}]
```

This turns off trig substitutions via `Trig -> False`, but then adds back in replacement of `Sin[a_]^2 + Cos[a_]^2` with `1`, while still performing the `Automatic` transformations. For example,

```
Simplify[Sin[x]^2 + Tan[x]^2 + Cos[x]^2, Trig -> False, 
 TransformationFunctions -> {Automatic, (# /. Sin[a_]^2 + Cos[a_]^2 :> 1) &}]
```

yields `1 + Tan[x]^2`, while

```
Simplify[Sin[x]^2 + Tan[x]^2 + Cos[x]^2]
```

yields `Sec[x]`.

Since you mentioned wanting it to be less cumbersome, note that you can package it into a function:

```
SCSimplify[expr_] := Simplify[expr, Trig -> False, 
 TransformationFunctions -> {Automatic, (# /. Sin[a_]^2 + Cos[a_]^2 :> 1) &}]
```

Comment: Thank you! This this exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

A quick solution could be applying substitution rules such as

```
expr1 = expr /. {Sin[x]^2 -> y, Cos[x]^2 -> 1 - y}
```

and then reinstating trigonometric functions after simplification as

```
expr2 = Simplify[expr1 /. {y -> Sin[x]^2}]
```

but @thorimur's solution in way more elegant.